# Keep same ID when copying webmap / web app map from ArcGIS Portal to another one

Tags: python, web-mapping, json, arcgis-portal

Webmaps are shared with an URL containing the ID.

Example: https://portal.com/portal/home/item.html?**id=8207f51d0c3d4b4193950beb2dcd21d4**

When a webmap configuration is replaced by another, for example from an import with https://ago-assistant.esri.com/#, the id's are recreated. The sharing URLs are therefore changed since the ID is changed.

I would like to copy a webmap / app from one portal to another always keeping the original ids.

> portal1:webmap:id:8207f51d0c3d4b4193950beb2dcd21d4 |_ copy to
> portal1:webmap:id:08fea3541c194075a94843645f733ccd

and vice/versa keeping the same ids

Can we use URLs on the name of the card?
How to move while maintaining the id?

I tried https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/cloning-content/#The-cloning-process with *item_mapping* parameter - This is a dictionary defined as *{'source_item_id': 'target_item_id' }*.
But it does not work. No items are cloned.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to specify the item ID. You must copy the item and then update any references to the item ID in any apps, etc. Using the cloning process can aid with that - I would recommend looking into why that's not working for you.